# If $\sin(t) = \frac{1}{2}$, why is $\sin (-t) = -\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

Given by an exercise in my book it is stated that:

$\sin(t) = \frac{1}{2}$

Evaluate $\sin (-t)$
The given answer is  $-\frac{1}{2}$.

Why is that so, when sin is an even function?

Answer (score 5):

$\sin(x)$ is an odd function. $\sin(-x) = -\sin(x)$ for all $x$. It is $\cos$ that is even.

Comment: Well, I feel really stupid now. Thank you.

Comment: Lol, don't feel that way. Now you know and will surely remember for future use.

Answer (score 1):

Using the sine of the difference you can see that
$$
\sin(-x) = \sin (0-x) = \sin 0 \cos x - \cos 0 \sin x = -\sin x
$$
so sine is indeed odd. Using a similar technique, you can show cosine is even as well.

Comment: It is also immediate from the geometric definition of $\sin$ as the $y$-coordinate of a point on the unit circle.

Comment: @Neal indeed, some prefer the geometric approach

Answer (score 0):

Consider the functions $f (x)=x $ this is called an odd function because $f (-x)=-x=-f (x).$ now consider $f (x)=x^2$ this is an even function because $f (x)=f (-x)=x^2$ in general not every function is even or odd but if they are then these properties hold.  now Sin (x) is an odd function because $\sin (\pi/2)=-\sin (-\pi/2) $ and all other sin (x). now we know that $sin (-t)=-sin(t)=-1/2$

Comment: Does -f(x) mean the same thing as -x?

Comment: no its more of that if f (x) is odd -f (x) means the same as f (-x)

Comment: also the parity of the function has to do with the symmetries of the plane such as reflections over x axis or y axis or line y=x.. these symmetries give rise to these properties.